# В header есть ссылка в блоке nav (логотип)

Tags: html, css

Хочу что бы при наведении на сам блок появлялся pointer, в данном случае он появляется только при наведении на текст. Подскажите, что поменять?

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#b3dced+0,29b8e5+50,bce0ee+100;Blue+Pipe */
background: rgb(179,220,237); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(179,220,237,1) 0%, rgba(41,184,229,1) 50%, rgba(188,224,238,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(179,220,237,1) 0%,rgba(41,184,229,1) 50%,rgba(188,224,238,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(179,220,237,1) 0%,rgba(41,184,229,1) 50%,rgba(188,224,238,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b3dced', endColorstr='#bce0ee',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}

section {
 width: 80%;
 height: 650px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 margin: auto;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

/*header*/
section header {
 height: 10%;
 width: 90%;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 margin: auto;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

section header .logo {
 width: 15%;
 height: 100%;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 position: relative;
}

section header .logo a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #2656D8;
}

section header .menu {
 width: 75%;
 height: 100%;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}

/*content*/
section content {
 height: 75%;
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 margin: auto;
}


/*footer*/
section footer {
 height: 10%;
 width: 90%;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Learning HTML&CSS</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/media.css">
</head>
<body>
 <section>
  <header>
   <nav class="logo"><a href="#">Learning HTML&CSS</a></nav>
   <nav class="menu">
    
   </nav>
  </header>
  <content>
   
  </content>
  <footer>
   
  </footer>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: сделайте "а" блочным элементом

Answer (score 0):

Надо чтоб при наведении на лого курсор менялся..

```
section header .logo:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Курсор появляется, но при нажатии на блок переход по ссылке не произойдет.

Comment: У вас нет никакого перехода при нажатии на блок, почему он должен произойти? 
Начиная с html 5 можно `<div></div>` оборачивать ссылкой, т.е. тегом `<a></a>`

Comment: Или вообще можно ссылку `<a></a>` "превратить" в блок - стилизировав, при этом и `<div></div>` никакой не нужен будет